# Hide attribute menu for admin role

Tags: magento2, admin, user-roles

I make a user role that needs to create a configurable product, to do this I need to give him the ACL for **Store/Attribute/product**.

But I don't want to let him create / add / delete an attribute, so I remove the *create new attribute* button in the configuration panel.

There is still one problem, the user can go to **Store > Attribute > Product** menu.

How can I make it invisible for my user role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 provide us "User Roles" for this issue.

1) Create new User Roles

2) **Assign Resources** like the image below to disable **Store > Attribute > Product**

[image]

This will be disabled **Store > Attribute > Product Menu** and when you add **configurable product**. User can't click button **Add Attributes**

You can reference this [document](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html)